# After migrating to AndroidX build fails with latest dependencies

Tags: flutter, androidx

I created a new fresh Flutter project and then migrated it to AndroidX using Android studio without any issue. Then I added all the latest dependencies to my project. But as and when I am trying to run the application the build fails...

> This version of cloud_firestore will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX

Below are my **pubspec.yaml** dependencies...

```
    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+3
    cloud_firestore: ^0.9.5+1
    firebase_core: ^0.3.1
    firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
    firebase_storage: ^2.1.0
    intl_translation: ^0.17.3
    http: ^0.12.0+1
    xml: ^3.3.1
    shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1
    flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.2.7
    google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
    flutter_signin_button: ^0.2.6
    image_picker: ^0.5.0+3
```

I have taken all the latest dependencies that should be compatible with AndroidX. Is there any way to resolve this issue without downgrading to the pre Androidx?

Please help...
Thank you for your time...

Comment: Did you solve your issue??

Answer (score 0):

use the cloud_firestore dependency which is compatible with androidx

```
cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
```

and follow this link to learn more about compatibility of flutter dependency with androidx. Use dependency which is mentioned here for your flutter dependency

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have already migrated to AndroidX. The dependency that you told is pre AndroidX.